# How to define persistence on Local Pivotal GemFire Region?

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have local `Region` and I want to persist the `Region` data to disk. How to define it using `DataPolicy`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure about what you're asking here, the question is not detailed enough... either way, the `DataPolicy` enumeration has the `PERSISTENT_REPLICATE` and `PERSISTENT_PARTITION` values which you can use when configuring a region to make it persistent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those 2 values are not supported in Local region. I am asking how I configure persistency on Java to Local (embeded) region?

Answer (score 0):

If your Region is truly "local", in that the data for the Region is only stored local to the GemFire data node (server) or perhaps your application if it is either a client or perhaps a peer member of the cluster (either way), then you can specify the data policy using the correct Region shortcut.

For example, if your application/arrangement is using a `ClientCache` (i.e. your application is a cache client), then you can still define LOCAL-only, persistent Regions using [`ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL_PERSISTENT`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientRegionShortcut.html#LOCAL_PERSISTENT).

If your application/arrangement is using a peer `Cache`, (i.e. your application is actually participating as a data node/server, peer member in the cluster), then you can still define LOCAL-only, persistent Regions using [`RegionShortcut.LOCAL_PERSISTENT`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/RegionShortcut.html#LOCAL_PERSISTENT).

By way of GemFire API (peer `Cache`):

```
Cache peerCache = new CacheFactory(..)
  .set(..)
  .create();

RegionFactory localPersistentServerRegion = 
  peerCache.createRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.LOCAL_PERSISTENT);
```

By way of GemFire API (`ClientCache`):

```
ClientCache clientCache = new ClientCacheFactory(..)
  .set(..)
  .create();

ClientRegionFactory localPersistentClientRegion = 
  clientCache.createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL_PERSISTENT);
```

By using SDG XML (peer `Cache`):

```
<gfe:local-region id="ExampleLocalPersistentServerRegion" persistent="true"/>
```

By using SDG XML (`ClientCache`):

```
<gfe:client-region id="ExampleLocalPersistentClientRegion" 
  shortcut="LOCAL_PERSISTENT"/>
```

By using SDG JavaConfig (peer `Cache`):

```
@Configuration
@PeerCacheApplication
class GemFireConfiguration {

  @Bean
  LocalRegionFactoryBean exampleLocalPersistentServerRegion(
      GemFireCache peerCache) {

    LocalRegionFactoryBean exampleRegion = 
      new LocalRegionFactoryBean();

    exampleRegion.setCache(peerCache);
    exampleRegion.setClose(false);
    exampleRegion.setPersistent(true);

    return exampleRegion;
}
```

By using SDG JavaConfig (`ClientCache`):

```
@Configuration
@ClientCacheApplication
class GemFireConfiguration {

  @Bean
  ClientRegionFactoryBean exampleLocalPersistentClientRegion(
      GemFireCache clientCache) {

    ClientRegionFactoryBean exampleRegion = 
      new ClientRegionFactoryBean();

    exampleRegion.setCache(peerCache);
    exampleRegion.setClose(false);
    exampleRegion.setPersistent(true);

    return exampleRegion;
}
```

There are also other ways of accomplishing the same using the pure [Annotation-based configuration model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-regions) in SDG, but this should get you going.

Cheers!
-John